# Unexpected response code 400?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley library and having issue of Unexpected response code 400.I am trying to login from username and password,but faced com.android.volley.ServerError.How can this be solved?

Login class

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText userName, Password;
    Button login;
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.0.106:84/Token";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserName";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    String username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_name);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        userName.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b' style='italic'>Username</font>"));
        Password.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b'>Password</font>"));
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void UserLogin() {

        username = userName.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                            openProfile();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("Charset", "UTF-8");
                return params;
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                map.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    private void openProfile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        UserLogin();
    }


    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/xml";
    }
}
```

How can this issue be solved?

After removing header i got this.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: No way of knowing without seeing the details of the server error. You're adding your headers to your parameters though, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: Error code 400 means bad request. Check at your server side what type of data it requires.

Comment: @Robby getHeaders() method also gives same error.

Comment: Remove content type.

Comment: @sourav Removing content type gives error  same error message

Comment: Then Check with server team what kind of request do they expect.

Comment: @Sourav if in the backend,there is OAuth  ,does in the Mobile also we have to do OAuth also through Mobile?

Comment: @seon No, you should check what kind of headers, params and etc. they expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135836/discussion-between-seon-and-sourav-ganguly).

Comment: From you screenshot, I guess your web service is Asp.Net Web API. You can still use your current `StringRequest`, then use an `JsonObject` to get the response data. Another way, you can use `JsonObjectRequest`. After getting the access token, store it then use it for other requests that need authorization

Comment: Can i store it in shared preference @BNK . Why the response data is not shown??

Comment: Of course you can store it in shared preference. Response data is a Json Object, different from "success" string, so it displays on screen `Toast.makeText(Login.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: How to store access token? i am not able to store access token @BNK

Comment: Why not? What error did you get? Have you tried https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294611/store-access-token-in-android-local-storage. Please look this @BNK


    public void onClick(View v) {


        UserLogin();
    }


}

Answer (score 0):

try this code 
This use POST method

```
final String URL = Vcruit.getInstance().GET_LOGIN;
    // Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("apikey", xxx.getInstance().API_KEY);
    params.put("userName", Username);
    params.put("password", Password);


        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONArray results = jObj.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject cat = results.getJSONObject(i);
                            String status = cat.getString("status");
                            String errormsg = cat.getString("ErrorMsg");

                            if (status.equals("Success")) {
                                                                } else {


                            }
                            }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    xxx.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-studio-volley-tutorial-to-create-a-login-application/

Comment: provide any useful links.please

Comment: i have to login not to register.@jins do you have login tutorial?it will help me if u send.

Comment: ok please try above code. but i think you are doing same thing..try removing header

Comment: removing header doesnot show the 400 error but not login is successful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135925/discussion-between-seon-and-jins-lukose).