# Store Access Token in Android Local Storage?

Tags: android, session, android-volley, token, shared

I am not able to Store access-token,username  in the SharedPreferences.How can this be Done?

Login Class

```
   public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText userName, Password;
Button login;
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserName";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
String username, password, accesstoken, tokentype;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_name);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    userName.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b' style='italic'>Username</font>"));
    Password.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b'>Password</font>"));
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void UserLogin() {

    username = userName.getText().toString().trim();
    password = Password.getText().toString().trim();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        accesstoken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                        tokentype = jsonObject.getString("token_type");
                        SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Login.this);
                        session.createLoginSession(accesstoken);
                        openProfile();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //  params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            map.put("grant_type", "password");
            return map;
        }
    };


    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


private void openProfile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    UserLogin();
}
```

}

SessionManagement class

```
   public class SessionManagement {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";


    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";


    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserName";

    public static final String KEY_access_token = "access_token";
    public static final String KEY_TOKEN_TYPE = "token_type";
    public static final String KEY_MASTER_ID = "MasterID";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_Access = "Name";


    // Constructor
    public SessionManagement(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     */
    public void createLoginSession(String username, String accesstoken, String tokentype, String masterid, String name, Integer access) {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_access_token, accesstoken);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, tokentype);

        editor.putString(KEY_MASTER_ID, masterid);
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, tokentype);
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putInt(KEY_Access, access);


        // commit changes


        String user_name_new = pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);

        Log.d("TAG", "Pass user name :" + username + " user_name_new:" + user_name_new);
        editor.commit();

    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));
        user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));

        user.put(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, pref.getString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, null));
        user.put(KEY_MASTER_ID, pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null));
        user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        user.put(KEY_Access, pref.getString(KEY_Access, null));


        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }

}
```

How the SessionManagement Class be used in the LOgin CLass to store information Locally??

Comment: What did you try so far? And what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: i have created session management class ,and dont know how to use it in the Login class

Comment: Create an object of `SessionManagement` class and call the respective methods when necessary.

Comment: You didn't update or set value for `accesstoken` variable (from the response data), should be done first inside `onResponse`

Comment: can you please give some code snippet.

Comment: Replace all the codes inside `onResponse` (including if...else) by sample code at http://pastebin.com/B3jrqN9H

Comment: No need, you have an accepted answer.

Comment: thank you very much @BNK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {

        //add these 2 lines
        SessionManagement session=new SessionManagement(Login.this);
        session.createLoginSession(username, accesstoken,tokentype, masterid,name, access);

        openProfile();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Edit your createLoginSession function:

```
 /**
 * Create login session
 * */
public void createLoginSession(String username, String accesstoken,String tokentype, String masterid,String name, Integer access){
    // Storing login value as TRUE


    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    // Storing name in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_access_token, accesstoken);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, tokentype);

    editor.putString(KEY_MASTER_ID, masterid);
    editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, tokentype);
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putInt(KEY_Access, access);




    // commit changes
    editor.commit();


    String user_name_new=pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null)

    Log.d("TAG","Pass user name :"+username+" user_name_new:"+user_name_new);
}
```

Comment: your createLoginSession is call or not.?Add log and print all values in createLoginSession  and check you get all value or not

Comment: i have edit createLoginSession  function use as it is and check the log value Pass user name  &  user_name_new in logcat

Comment: Means your value is store into SharedPreferences  then what is issue ?

Comment: sorry for mistake,username is not printed in the log

Comment: Means your onResponse method is not call in login activity.Check your response.Post your updated code

Comment: Updated Code are posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135947/discussion-between-seon-and-user2025187).

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preference to hold the login details/access token. please go through the code snippet.

```
public class Preferences {
public static void setAccessToken(@NonNull Context context, String token) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ACCESSTOKEN", token);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getAccessToken(@NonNull Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("ACCESSTOKEN", null);
}}
```

similarly, you can store the username and password to shared prefs and retrieve them as you required.

Comment: Where to instantiate this class in the Login class?

Comment: you don't have to instantiate the class since the methods are static you can access directly. Upon success of login api, the token from the server and username/password can be saved.

Comment: where i have to use Preferences class.,within the login class?

Comment: Inside onResponse()

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to save any type of data in local storage will works perfectly, Because this is running code of my application.**

> 1. Firstly create a static instance of your application in your application class. And in this application class make static instance of your PreferenceManager class where all operations will done.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public static MyApp myApp ;
public static MyPreferenceManager myPreferenceManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    myApp = this;

  }

/*For creating the context of the Whole app.*/
public static MyApp getInstance() {
    return myApp ;
}

/*This is for getting the instance of the MyPreferenceManager class using the context of MyApp App.*/
public static MyPreferenceManager getPreferenceManager() {
    if (myPreferenceManager == null) {
        myPreferenceManager = new MyPreferenceManager(getInstance());
    }

    return myPreferenceManager;
}

}
```

> 2. Now code of your MyPreferenceManager class :

```
public class MyPreferenceManager {

Context context;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "com.example.App";

public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

public MyPreferenceManager(Context context) {

    this.context = context;

    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.apply();

}

public void putString(String key, String value) {

    editor.putString(key, value);

    editor.apply();

}

public String getString(String key) {

    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);

}

//Method to clear the login data of the application.
public void clearLoginData() {

    editor.remove(KEY_ID);
    editor.remove(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    editor.apply();

}

}
```

> 3. Now from any where you can save data to local storage from this code below.

```
MyApp.getInstance().getPreferenceManager().putString(MyPreferenceManager.KEY_ID, "1");
MyApp.getInstance().getPreferenceManager().putString(MyPreferenceManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, "oihfodfdshfhfoifhoifh3393");
```

> 4. Now from any where you can get data from local storage from this code below.

```
String id = MyApp.getInstance().getPreferenceManager().getString(MyPreferenceManager.KEY_ID);
String accessToken = MyApp.getInstance().getPreferenceManager().getString(MyPreferenceManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

> Thanks.